# COUNTIF Formula moves down when row at top added

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following `COUNTIF` Formula in my Google Sheet.

```js
=COUNTIFS('Events/Incidents'!$E$3:$E,X4,'Events/Incidents'!$I$3:$I,"Accident")
```

This is a sample of the sheet which has the formula in the first row under the "Accidents" header:

[image]

It works until a user adds a row 3 to the top of the source sheet (Events/Incidents) then the formula changes to the following so that it captures row 4 down instead of the desired row 3.

```js
=COUNTIFS('Events/Incidents'!$E$4:$E,X4,'Events/Incidents'!$I$4:$I,"Accident")
```

I used the Query function for "All Events" (the first 3 columns). The Countif formula is under each of the Incidents. In my Countif example, X4 is the Employee, John White which was returned in the QUERY.

The QUERY continues to return/include row 3 but I don't know how to do this for the individual Incidents. I tried adding `ArrayFormula` to the `Countif` function but I have the same problem.

Would appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out by combining Countifs with ImportRange:

```js
=COUNTIFS(IMPORTRANGE("1-f6OU8ylDSlpqdpt4P5B7GDcIel3IboVkUbY2huMA6U","Events/Incidents!$E$3:$E"),X4,IMPORTRANGE("1-f6OU8ylDSlpqdpt4P5B7GDcIel3IboVkUbY2huMA6U","Events/Incidents!$I$3:$I"),"Accident")
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to update your `QUERY` to reflect the correct row without resorting to returning the `Branch` in every response. If my comprehension is correct, there is a way to reach your goals with little modification.

First, you'll have to create a [named range](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175) that includes the whole table (from the headers to the last row). You can then use this named range in every formula so new rows can be detected without changing the formula per se.

Finally, you can modify your [`QUERY`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) to return only the values of `Incidents` in a `Branch` with something similar to `=QUERY(myNamedRange,"SELECT G WHERE A = 'Auckland'")`. That `QUERY` won't return the `Branch`, only the `Incidents`. If you keep having any doubts, please ask me for further help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry, that's not quite what I'm after so I have changed my question slightly and given a different example to try and make it clearer. The issue is that we have over 300 employees so I don't know which Employee the QUERY is going to return. The first 3 columns are returned from the QUERY which is counting the highest no. of events. The last 3 have the countif formula to determine the breakdown of certain incidents by the Employee returned in the QUERY.

Comment: Hi @McChief! I apologize because I can't imagine your situation. Could you please share a replica of your initial Sheet so I can work on it? Share too a sheet or image of your desired results so I can understand it.